# Scala 2D array sorting by primary and secondary colums

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting

For a 2D array such as

```
val in = Array( Array(1, 45, 32), 
                Array(2, 88, 5), 
                Array(3, 72, 5) )
```

how to sort it by the third column (primary choice) and if equality by the second column (secondary choice), so that the result looks like this,

```
val out = Array( Array(3, 72, 5),
                 Array(2, 88, 5),
                 Array(1, 45, 32) )
```

In general, for a 2D matrix with `m` columns, how to specify up to `m` choices ?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provide `sortBy` with the desired ordering which in this case is the column.

```
scala> in.sortBy(x => (x(2), x(1)))
res4: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(
                            Array(3, 72, 5),
                            Array(2, 88, 5),
                            Array(1, 45, 32))
```

You can pass `sortBy` a `Tuple` of columns to sort by. So, to sort by three columns you can pass in `x => x(1), x(2), x(3))` and so on.